# SQL Query Writing Help - Multiple Lookups in One Record

Tags: sql

I am an IT analyst attempting to learn some SQL to help me work with developers in a more efficient manner.  Gave myself a little personal project to help me learn SQL and ran into some issues that I hope you all can help me with.

**Background**

I have an interest in darts, so I would like to create a DB to log each of my turns.  If you are unfamiliar with darts, each turn consists of three throws at the dartboard.

I am designing a DB with two tables:

1. "Turns" keeps track of each player's turn.

   - TurnID is the primary key, and is an auto-incremented integer.
   - Throw1 contains the result of the player's first throw.
   - Throw2 contains the result of the player's second throw.
   - Throw3 contains the result of the player's third throw.
2. "ScoreValues" is a reference table that lists a score and the number of points that the score is worth.  Each record associates one "score" with a "value".  The "Score" is the primary key.

   - Score is the primary key, and represents one possible outcome of a throw.
   - Value contains the value of the player's throw.  So an "S20" is worth 20 points.

**Table Excerpts/Samples**

Turns

```
TurnID   Throw1   Throw2   Throw3
101      S20      S16      S18
102      S16      S19      S17
```

ScoreValues

```
Score   Value
S20     20
S19     19
S18     18
S17     17
S16     16
S15     15
```

**Query**

This is where the challenge begins.  I am looking for a query that will generate an output that looks like below:

```
TurnID   Throw1   Throw2   Throw3   Throw1Value   Throw2Value   Throw3Value
101      S20      S16      S18      20            16            18
102      S16      S19      S17      16            19            17
```

If I run the following query, I can *sort of* get what I'm looking for, but only for Throw1:

```
SELECT Turns.TurnID, Turns.Throw1, Turns.Throw2, Turns.Throw3, ScoreValues.Value
FROM Turns
INNER JOIN  Values on Turns.Throw1 = ScoreValues.Score
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I can get my intended output?  Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks!

K

Comment: Try 'pivot' table way.

Comment: The answer depends on your rdbms, something you did not specify.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I don't like seeing duplicate answers, but there was no answer when I posted mine, which is obviously the same thing as @jmo1687.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you are looking for. I'm used to Oracle, but hopefully it will work for other flavors as well:

```
SELECT T.TurnID, 
    T.Throw1, 
    T.Throw2, 
    T.Throw3,
    (SELECT value from ScoreValues where score = t.Throw1) as Throw1Value,
    (SELECT value from ScoreValues where score = t.Throw2) as Throw2Value,
    (SELECT value from ScoreValues where score = t.Throw3) as Throw3Value,
FROM Turns t
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  This worked like a charm.  I am actually designing this DB within Access 2007, and was able to make this work with a minor tweak - just added "AS" in your select statements i.e., (SELECT value from ScoreValues where score = t.Throw1) AS Throw1Value

Comment: Great! I modified the answer to make it more platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that you are limiting the result set to Throw1.  Any filtering/limiting, you probably want to use TurnId in the where clause.  In your example, no where clause is called for. For something this simple, you can use the following:

```
SELECT TurnId, Throw1, Throw2, Throw3, ThrowValue1 = 
(select value from ScoreValues where Score = Throw1),
ThrowValue2 = (select value from ScoreValues where Score = Throw2),
ThrowValue3 = (select value from ScoreValues where Score = Throw3)
FROM Turns
```

Here are a couple of sites that explain Pivot Tables, which is the concept of representing row values by columns.  As the complexity of the query grows, you'll want to use this:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx